# Improve "resolution" of random data

Tags: ruby, random

I've been working on an [MPD](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki) front end in Ruby, with the ability to play a random album.

```
album = all[(rand*all.length).floor]
```

Where `all` is an array of the names of all albums in the library, chooses the album to play.

This works, however, I find it plays some albums more than others, and sometimes very obviously (I've seen it play the same album twice in a row, more than once, my library has a few hundred albums, so this should statistically be *very* unlikely to happen), and on the other end, a lot of albums never get played.

Is there any way that I can get a more random number? Is there a gem that implements a better random number algorithm? Do I need to change the seed?

Comment: "Very" unlikely, no. If you've got, say, 300 albums, the chances of playing the same thing twice in a row are about 1 in 300...

Comment: It's actually quite likely, see the "birthday paradox": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem Out of 365 possible birthdays, in a random group of 23 people the chances are better than 50% that at least two of them will have the same birthday. Translated to songs, if you play 23 songs at random from a 365 song collection, it's better than 50% chance that the same song will show up twice. In two hours/40 songs, you have ~12% chance of getting the same song twice in a row. This is one of the less intuitive effects of randomness :)

Comment: j-g-faustus, this is why I need to learn more about statistics! Thanks for posting that, and to everyone else who posted in an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of doing a new random selection every time, shuffle the list once and then just take albums off that shuffled queue until you feel like resetting.

```
queue = albums.sort_by{rand}
while next = queue.pop
   play next
end
```

Comment: Hear, hear, Glenn's got it. This is why "shuffle" mode is called "shuffle" and not "random"--because the program "shuffles" the albums like a deck of cards and then draws the next one off the top each time.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will improve the results or not, but you can do `rand(all.length)` to get an integer directly.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, lots of folks think the random shuffle of the IPod Shuffle isn't random either.  So this puts you in good company. :-)

http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=89408926&ft=1&f=1006

http://www.cnet.com.au/itunes-just-how-random-is-random-339274094.htm?omnRef=NULL

A main point of the above articles is human's sense of what is random is flawed.  You probably do have a random selection.

But you may want to implement a similar "random but no repeats" feature as the IPod Shuffle has.  Or "random but biased towards favorites."

Comment: I second the flawed perception comment.  Usually, when people complain about things being insufficiently random, what they actually want are things to be *less* random.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [Normally Distributed Random Numbers](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/162967#715915)

You should also check [RandomR](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/randomr/)